# Is there a way to store HTML file text into an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, file

I want to extract all the words from the HTML file and store them into a textarea as follows. Is there any way to grab all this content in an array using Javascript? Any tips would be much appreciated.

```
<textarea id="url" name="url" type="Text"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:oF(document.getElementById('url').value)">Open File</a>

<script>
var f;
function oF(url) {
    f = window.open();
    f.location = url;
}
</script>
```

What I need is, when I click the URL [open file] the html scripts will be stored in that textarea.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. What is "all this content" that needs to be stored, and why to an array? What does the code have to do with it?

Comment: I want to extract all the words from the HTML file and store them into a table showing each word and its occurrences. Since I'm quite new to javascript I thought I could use an array to it.

Comment: When you say "words from the HTML file," do you mean what is visible on screen or the actual HTML?

Comment: What is visible in the screen. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you're wanting to take HTML and extract as many words as you can out of it to get a word count.  If that's so, this may be what you want:

```
function stripHtml(html) {
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}

var str = "<p>I'm a word!! </p><p>Me too!!!!!</p>";

//Strip the HTML and remove puncuation
str = stripHtml(str).toLowerCase();
str = str.replace(/[!@#$%^&*\(\)\.?\{\}\[\]|<>,-=_+']/g,'');

//Split into an array of words
var words = str.split(/\b/g);
```

From there you have an array of all of the words in the document, and you just have to count them.  Good luck :)